# TypeError: g.j is undefined (Google Map) While migrating it to Javascript OOP

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, oop

I am trying to migrate my existing working Google Map code into Javascript Object Based fashion, But I am running into some error, not able to figure it out .Initially all markers are loaded, and on any events (click, drag etc) its throwing the error **TypeError: g.j is undefined**.

I guess below lines are the cause of error:

```
   google.maps.event.addListener(mapObj.polymap, "dragend", mapObj.mapSearch());
        google.maps.event.addListener(mapObj.polymap.getPath(), "insert_at", mapObj.mapSearch());
        google.maps.event.addListener(mapObj.polymap.getPath(), "remove_at", mapObj.mapSearch());
        google.maps.event.addListener(mapObj.polymap.getPath(), "set_at", mapObj.mapSearch());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the 3rd argument of `google.maps.event.addListener` is expected to be a function, but you provide function-calls, not functions.

You must remove the parentheses after the function-name:

```
    google.maps.event.addListener(mapObj.polymap, "dragend", mapObj.mapSearch);
    google.maps.event.addListener(mapObj.polymap.getPath(), "insert_at", mapObj.mapSearch);
    google.maps.event.addListener(mapObj.polymap.getPath(), "remove_at", mapObj.mapSearch);
    google.maps.event.addListener(mapObj.polymap.getPath(), "set_at", mapObj.mapSearch);

//.................

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', mapObj.init);
```

Comment: But basically your approach isn't really OOP, you simply define functions in a object and call these functions, but these functions are not methods of the object itself(what would be OOP). I have to go to work now, I will show you how to do it the OOP-way later

Comment: sir, please can you provide your oop version